# js function does not run in array element in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

When i try to execute this code:

```
$('.pagination-item')[$('.blog-item:visible').index()].addClass("active");
```

in IE8 there is the message:

> object doesn't support property or method 'addclass'

Actually not even .hide() or .show() can be executed agains the $('.pagination-item')[0]. I suspect that there is something wrong with the array element management in IE8. Do you have any clue on it? Why does this error appear?

Comment: _HTMLElement_ and _Node_ don't have an _addClass_ in their _prototypes_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access a jquery object using indexer like this, the returned object is a DOM object which does not have jquery methods. You could try:

```
$('.pagination-item:eq('+ $('.blog-item:visible').index() +')').addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('.pagination-item')[$('.blog-item:visible').index()]` returns a dom object reference, not a jQuery wrapper object so it does not have the `addClass` method.

You can use [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq)

```
$('.pagination-item').eq($('.blog-item:visible').index()).addClass("active");
```

Comment: you are right, i was confused as it worked in Chrome, Safari, IE9 but not in IE8. Anyway this works everywhere! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$('.pagination-item')[$('.blog-item:visible').index()].addClass("active");
```

to

```
    var index = $('.blog-item:visible').index();
    $('.pagination-item').eq(index).addClass("active");
```

it isn't pretty, but it should work.